# When I try to read the Json file I get the error "JSON parse error Invalid value"

Tags: c#, json, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to load a Json file, but it gives an error, in Unity Editor Everything works, but in Android it gives an error. The error happens on the next line

```
WordsData loadedData = JsonUtility.FromJson<WordsData>(dataAsJson);
```

File read function

```
IEnumerator GetWordLevelData()
{
    Debug.Log("1");
    data = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    Debug.Log("2");
    string filePath;
    Debug.Log("3");
    filePath = Path.Combine(Application.streamingAssetsPath, language + "/" + LevelScrambled + ".json");
    string dataAsJson;
    Debug.Log("4");
    if (filePath.Contains("://") || filePath.Contains(":///"))
    {
        Debug.Log("5");
        UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.Get(filePath);
        Debug.Log("6");
        yield return www.Send();
        Debug.Log("7");
        dataAsJson = www.downloadHandler.text;
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.Log("8");
        dataAsJson = File.ReadAllText(filePath);
    }
    Debug.Log("9");
    WordsData loadedData = JsonUtility.FromJson<WordsData>(dataAsJson);
    Debug.Log("10");
    for (int i = 0; i < loadedData.items.Length; i++)
    {
        data.Add(loadedData.items[i].key, loadedData.items[i].value);
    }
    Debug.Log("11");

}
```

classes

```
[System.Serializable]
public class WordsData
{
    public WordsItem[] items;
}


[System.Serializable]
public class WordsItem
{
    public string key;
    public string value;
}
```

Json File

```
{
    "items":[
    {
            "key": "Mask",
            "value": "ADULT"
    },  
    {
            "key": "Words",
            "value": "dog/next/ant/top/"
    },
    {
            "key": "LettersPerCost",
            "value": "O1/G2/N1/E1/X3/T2/T1/O1/P3/"
    }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error in this line:

```
filePath = Path.Combine(Application.streamingAssetsPath, language + "/" + LevelScrambled + ".json");
```

It is not possible to access the StreamingAssets folder on WebGL and Android platforms. No file access is available on WebGL. Android uses a compressed .apk file.
Try created new file by path, used `Application.persistentDataPath`. For example:

```
private string GetJsonPath()
{
#if !UNITY_EDITOR && (UNITY_IOS || UNITY_ANDROID)
    try
    {
        Directory.CreateDirectory(Application.persistentDataPath);
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
    }
    return Application.persistentDataPath + "/LevelScrambled.json";
#else
    try
    {
        Directory.CreateDirectory(Application.streamingAssetsPath);
    }
    catch(Exception)
    {
    }

    return Application.streamingAssetsPath + "/LevelScrambled.json";
#endif
}
```